# Calling Win32's Sleep function from assembly creates access violation error

Tags: c++, winapi, assembly, x86, calling-convention

I'm using MASM and Visual C++, and I'm compiling in x64. This is my C++ code:

```
// include directive
#include "stdafx.h"
// external functions
extern "C" int Asm();
// main function
int main()
{

    // call asm
    Asm();
    // get char, return success
    _getch();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and my assembly code:

```
extern Sleep : proc
; code segment
.code
    ; assembly procedure
    Asm proc
        ; sleep for 1 second
        mov ecx, 1000   ; ecx = sleep time
        sub rsp, 8      ; 8 bytes of shadow space
        call Sleep      ; call sleep
        add rsp, 8      ; get rid of shadow space
        ; return
        ret
    Asm endp
end
```

Using breakpoints, I've pinpointed the line of code where the access violation occurs: right after the `ret` statement in my assembly code.

Extra info:

- I'm using the *fastcall* convention to pass my parameters into `Sleep` (even though it is declared as *stdcall*), because [from what I have read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx), x64 will always use the *fastcall* convention.
- My `Asm` procedure compiles and executes with no errors when I get rid of the `Sleep` related code.
- Even when I try to call `Sleep` with the *stdcall* convention, I still get an access violation error.

So obviously, my question is, how do I get rid of the access violation error, what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

This is the generated assembly for `Sleep(500);` in C++:

```
mov         ecx,1F4h  
call        qword ptr [__imp_Sleep (13F54B308h)]
```

This generated assembly is confusing me... it looks like fastcall because it moves the parameter into ecx, but at the same time it doesn't create any shadow space. And I have no clue what this means: 
 `qword ptr [__imp_Sleep (13F54B308h)]`.

**And again, edit, the full disassembly for `main`.**

```
int main()
{
000000013F991020  push        rdi  
000000013F991022  sub         rsp,20h  
000000013F991026  mov         rdi,rsp  
000000013F991029  mov         ecx,8  
000000013F99102E  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
000000013F991033  rep stos    dword ptr [rdi]  
Sleep(500); // this here is the asm generated by the compiler!
000000013F991035  mov         ecx,1F4h  
000000013F99103A  call        qword ptr [__imp_Sleep (13F99B308h)]  
// call asm
Asm();
000000013F991040  call        @ILT+5(Asm) (13F99100Ah)  
// get char, return success
_getch();
000000013F991045  call        qword ptr [__imp__getch (13F99B540h)]  
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
000000013F99104B  xor         eax,eax  
}
```

Comment: As Sleep is an OS API I doubt it uses fastcall. AFAIK fastcall is only used for functions defined by you. Compile the call in C and look at the assembly generated. I think WINAPI functions are all stdcall

Comment: Calling Sleep from asm seems a bit silly :) +1 to James - that's what I was about to say.

Comment: I suggest you write and compile an x64 executable using normal C/C++ first and then use a disassembler to see what kind of x64 assembly code was generated, then you can replicate that in your assembly code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I edited my question, look at the bottom. Any advice?

Comment: @James: in x64, there is only one stanardized calling convention.  The compiler silently maps/ignores the `__stdcall` and `__cdecl` calling conventions for backwards compatibility with x86 code, but really those calling conventions do not exist in x64. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms235286.aspx: "Given the expanded register set, x64 just uses the __fastcall calling convention and a RISC-based exception-handling model."

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've read that article and I use the calling convention it talks about, but it doesn't seem to work. (Isn't the calling convention it talks about in that article exactly what I'm doing in my asm code?)

Comment: @RemyLebeau seems you're right!

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus you don't need to mess with the stack as it's not used. The a qword ptr stuff just means 'call the function at abcdefabh'. The linker decides this address.

Comment: @James Okay, I got rid of add/sub rsp, but I still get the violation error...

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you mean that it's the responsibility of the *calle* to set up shadow space, and not the *caller*? Also, like I said above, it still crashes when I remove the add/sub stuff.

Comment: @are you sure you copied all the assembly code generated? I do not have a compiler to hand right now

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus: the *caller* allocates shadow space for the parameters it passes to the *callee*. You need the `SUB RSP, 8` instruction because you are `CALL`ing your own `Asm()` function. The compiler's `CALL Asm` instruction will misalign the stack (`CALL` pushes 8 bytes onto the stack), requiring `Asm()` to `SUB RSP, 8` to re-align the stack back to a 16-byte boundary. `Asm()` then needs to allocate additional stack space for the parameter it wants to pass to `Sleep()`. You are not allocating that extra space.

Comment: @James I'll put all of the diasssembly for main in the question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Like this? `sub rsp, 8 | mov ecx, 1000 | call Sleep | ret`. I'm still getting the error...

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus: no, you need something more like this instead: `sub rsp, 8 | move ecx, 1000 | sub rsp, 8 | call Sleep | add rsp, 16 | ret`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Error again... Sleep, you are a nightmare. (haha)

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus: I only work with x86 assembly, so my x64 is a little rusty. The following is what my x64 compiler generates, but I'm sure the extra stack frame is not ideal in this situation: `push rbp | sub rsp,32 |
mov rbp,rsp | mov ecx, 1000 | call Sleep | lea rsp,[rbp+32] | pop rbp | ret` I suggest you map it out on paper and see exactly what the stack is really doing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Great, it worked! I have to go, but post an answer and the next time I get on, I'll accept it and +1 it. Thank you very much, this question must have been a pain.

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus: similar to your compiler's x64 output, my x64 compiler also is not allocating any shadow space when calling Sleep() in plain ordinary code.

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus: [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235286.aspx): "The caller is responsible for allocating space for parameters to the callee, and **must always allocate sufficient space for the 4 register parameters, even if the callee doesn’t have that many parameters.**"

Comment: Not sure why you say it doesn't create any shadow space. "sub rsp, 20h" creates the shadow space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `Asm()` were a normal C/C++ function, eg:

```
void Asm()
{
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

The following is what my x64 compiler generates for it:

```
Asm proc
    push rbp          ; re-aligns the stack to a 16-byte boundary (CALL pushed 8 bytes for the caller's return address) as well as prepares for setting up a stack frame
    sub rsp, 32       ; 32 bytes of shadow space
    mov rbp, rsp      ; finalizes the stack frame using the current stack pointer
    ; sleep for 1 second
    mov ecx, 1000     ; ecx = sleep time
    call Sleep        ; call sleep
    lea rsp, [rbp+32] ; get rid of shadow space
    pop rbp           ; clears the stack frame and sets the stack pointer back to the location of the caller's return address
    ret               ; return to caller
Asm endp
```

[MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170):

> The caller is responsible for allocating space for parameters to the callee, and **must always allocate sufficient space for the 4 register parameters, even if the callee doesn’t have that many parameters.**

Have a look at the following page for more information about how x64 uses the stack:

[Stack Allocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/stack-usage?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Thank you very much! That stack allocation article is very usefull.